# Libcurl - parameter CURLMOPT_SOCKETFUNCTION

Tags: c, libcurl

Tell me please, Here's what I did with Libcurl:

1)Create easy_handles. (curl_easy_init)

2)Create multi_handle. (curl_multi_init)

3)On multi_handle set paremetrs: curl_easy_setopt: CURLMOPT_SOCKETFUNCTION and CURLMOPT_TIMERFUNCTION

4)Added to the multi_handle ---> easy_handles. (curl_multi_add_handle)

5)Next, was called the function callback_timer() (CURLMOPT_TIMERFUNCTION)

6)In this function call_back_timer, I call the function curl_multi_socket_action().

7)Next, was called callback_socket_function (CURLMOPT_SOCKETFUNCTION):

```
int socket_callback(CURL *easy,      /* easy handle */
                    curl_socket_t s, /* socket */
                    int what,        /* describes the socket */
                    void *userp,     /* private callback pointer */
                    void *socketp);  /* private socket pointer */
```

8)In callback_socket_function - what == 1 == CURL_POLL_IN:

> CURL_POLL_IN: Wait for incoming data. For the socket to become readable.

Tell me Please: What is meant in this case by - "incoming data" ?

What do I need to do next with all this?

I have to call functions Send/Recv, WSASend/WSARecv for curl_socket_t ?

Answer (score -1):

Incoming data means the data that is going to recieve from server which request asked for.

I suggest to follow from examples provided by Libcurl because working with Socket function actually needs event library for easy programming but it is optional see this link:

https://curl.se/libcurl/c/multi-uv.html

Comment: @SAH, I am using my IO completion port Windows implementation and trying to merge it with libcurl. I don’t understand how yet.       Please tell me, what data has libcurl already received from the server? After all, in order for libcurl to send a message to the server using IO completion port i - the socket must be attached to the completion port, and libcurl definitely did not do this and the WSASend function is used. I'm confused.

Comment: The socketfunction gets called to inform you that you need to wait for activity X on socket Y. When you later detect such activity, you need to tell libcurl about it (by calling curl_multi_socket_action).

Comment: @Daniel Stenberg, Thank you!, but the fact is that the IO Completion Port Windows only works with calls WSASend/WSARecv, But inside libcurl there are no calls to these functions. There is only - Send/Recv. How then does libcurl work with IOCP Windows ?